# Drupal module Date 2.7 update - Database Table name

Tags: 7, updating

I just updated the Drupal7 module ***Date*** from 2.9 to 2.10.  There is a database table update that acccompanies that module update.  What is the name of the database table that is updated?  (or can you direct me where to find that information?)

Attaching screenshot of the database update performed when installing the date module.  What are ***Date text widgets***?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what tables are being updated, you can just go to `/update.php` of your site (you need to be logged in first) to apply these updates. You don't do them manually.

To find what was updated, you can look in the `CHANGELOG.txt` if the module has one, or, look in the install file for the module being updated within Date. It should have an applicable update hook that will show you (in code) what is being changed.

This is a [list of everything that was changed](https://www.drupal.org/project/date/releases/7.x-2.10) in the last release.

Comment: I have already updated the date module but the database change that the installer implemented caused my custom theme to crash in some places.  That's the reason I'm trying to find the specific table that was changed so I can roll it back.  The CHANGELOG.txt file only shows changes up to version 2.8 and nothing for 2.10.  The install file gives no information about database changes.  The list of changes on the Drupal module page doesn't appear to list any database changes.